# Quarkus - Docker image fails

Tags: docker, quarkus

I bootstrapped a plain vanilla Quarkus application via https://code.quarkus.io
and the generated code does not build the docker image successfully on my Mac.

When executing

```
mvn clean package
```

and
    docker build -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile.jvm -t quarkus/tet-code-with-quarkus-jvm .

I receive the following error at the end:

```
(microdnf:410): librhsm-WARNING **: 09:15:48.174: Found 0 entitlement certificates

(microdnf:410): librhsm-WARNING **: 09:15:48.176: Found 0 entitlement certificates

(microdnf:410): libdnf-WARNING **: 09:15:48.177: Loading "/etc/dnf/dnf.conf": IniParser: Can't open file
Complete.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
The command '/bin/sh -c microdnf install curl ca-certificates ${JAVA_PACKAGE}     && microdnf update     && microdnf clean all     && mkdir /deployments     && chown 1001 /deployments     && chmod "g+rwX" /deployments     && chown 1001:root /deployments     && curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/fabric8/run-java-sh/${RUN_JAVA_VERSION}/run-java-sh-${RUN_JAVA_VERSION}-sh.sh -o /deployments/run-java.sh     && chown 1001 /deployments/run-java.sh     && chmod 540 /deployments/run-java.sh     && echo "securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom" >> /etc/alternatives/jre/lib/security/java.security' returned a non-zero code: 35
```

Note sure if this is related to the issue but since I am behind a company proxy I set the proxies in the .docker/config.json like this:

```
"proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
     "httpsProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
     "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com"
   }
 }
```

I assume this is the reason for not building the image:
**curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number** but I do not know hot to solve it.
I tested the same on my private computer (Windows10) and it works. Must be something with the surrounding environment (proxy, Mac specific ?)

Btw: The native image using GraalVM was built successfully

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by myself: It was related to my proxy settings which have been wrong. After fixing the same in the `.docker/config.json` file and restarting the docker engine it worked and built the image successfully.